# Obtaning the AST of JavaScript code from Spidermonkey

Tags: c++, abstract-syntax-tree, spidermonkey

I need to obtain the AST of a JS code from C++. I know that Spidermonkey's (unlike V8's generated) ASTs follow a standard that I could use.

Can I pass it a code (string or JS file) from a C++ program and get the AST? If so how?

Comment: where you able to get an answer to this?

Comment: no, there doesn't seems to be a lot of answers to the spidermonkey tag :(

Comment: Do you want to embed SpiderMonkey or just call-out to a compiled SpiderMonkey shell?

Comment: I would prefer to embed it, but at this point I'll take anything that works

Answer (score 2):

I just answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674368/spidermonkey-variables-list/32057773#32057773). The short version is:

1. Build a runtime, context, and global object as outlined [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_User_Guide#A_minimal_example)
2. `JS_InitReflect` with your global to instantiate the `Reflect` object in the global scope ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Parser_API))
3. Write a bit of JS to parse the code you wish to analyze. Depending on your needs, you may just want to do the analysis in JavaScript or hand a JSON encoded string back to your C++.