# SpiderMonkey variables list

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, spidermonkey

I have a QT application in which I want to embed SpiderMonkey. With it I want to parse javascript segment (not execute it) and retrieve all the variables, functions, objects, arrays, etc. in some kind of a structured tree or just list them... Is that possible?

I've looked through the documentation, but could not find anything.

Or perhaps someone can point me to another parser if I can't do that with SpiderMonkey?

Answer (score 0):

If you must do this with a SpiderMonkey embedding, you can use the `JS_InitReflect` function to create a `Reflect` object in the current global context ([documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20210619033034/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Parser_API)). It would require you to write a script to run `Relect.parse(/* your javascript segment */)`, but then you've got the AST in a JS object hierarchy. At that point, it should be easy to export a JSON string or whatever you need back to your native code.

It would probably be a lot easier to use a project like [Esprima](http://esprima.org/) and spawn a Node.js process to print out the AST for the JS you want to analyze instead of dealing with the trouble of a full on SpiderMonkey embedding.